# How to deploy two different react app on ec2 server using nginx or any other better method

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, deployment, mern

I have two react apps one for the client and one for the admins. What I want is to deploy both apps on a single ec2 server. For now, I don't have a domain name so I want to use the public IP address of the ec2 server as my domain. I have tried many ways to deploy using nginx but none of them works. I managed to deploy the client app successfully but the admin is not working. I want the admin app to be a subdomain of the client app so in my case, if let's say the public IP address of my ec2 server is 12.12.12.12, the admin URL should be admin.12.12.12.12. Both apps use react-router and have multiple pages in case this is required to know for the static file location.
I tried to create two different configuration file for both the client and admin in the /etc/nginx/sites-available/ folder and linked them.FYI I used pm2 to deploy the node js server and it is running fine.

client configuration

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 12.12.12.12;

    root /var/www/client/build;
    index index.html;

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_redirect http://localhost:5000 http://$host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

admin configuration file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name admin.12.12.12.12;

    root /var/www/admin/build;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Buying a domain name and replacing the IP address with the domain name is the simplest solution.